# prevent access to a subfolder in a domain after a redirect

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

Assuming i have the following "mydomain.com" that has is pointed to the folder "public_html".

I wanted to redirect all *mydomain.com* to *mydomain.com/prod/public* folder so i edited the .htaccess file as follows:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?mydomain.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/prod/public/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /prod/public/$1

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?mydomain.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ prod/public/index.php [L]
```

the changes work as expected, YAY!!!

how do i prevent access to the site via the following request:

```
http://mydomain.com/prod/public/
```

or

```
 http://mydomain.com/prod/public/index.php
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place this rule as first rule in your `prod/public/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine on

# direct access forbidden
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+prod/public(/index\.php|/?)?[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

Comment: sorry the issues still persists

Comment: So you entering `http://mydomain.com/prod/public/index.php` in browser and it is showing normal content?

Comment: Is there any .htaccess in prod or prod/public?

Comment: <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options -MultiViews
    RewriteEngine On

 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>

Comment: the code i posted in the question is in the root directory /public_html, the code i posted in the commend is in prod/public

Comment: Okay in that case place my `# direct access forbidden` rule from above into `prod/public/.htaccess` as first rule just below `RewriteEngine On` line

Comment: thank you.. this worked, one more question how to i wire it to let the framework handle with a 404

Comment: For 404 you can replace `RewriteRule ^ - [F]` with `RewriteRule ^ - [L,R=404]`